# Fuzzy string match in postgres jsonb column

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a jsonb column in a postgres table called *topics* which is a literal array of strings. An example record might have this for a *topics* value:

`['healthcare', 'fitness', 'gains', 'doyouevenliftbro']`

I need to find this record among many which would match `%lift%`

All the other queries I'm finding on stackoverflow and the pg docs can match against `doyouevenliftbro` as a complete string, or can do a regex match if this is converted from `json_to_recordset()` or whatever, but then they go on to reference properties inside the JSON, which this doesn't have. Hoping it's simple syntax that's just evading me. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use `json_array_elements` to un-nest the `json` array to a set. Once it's a set, you can apply the `like` operator and throw it in a subquery.

```
select *
from your_table
where exists (
  select *
  from json_array_elements(your_table.topics::json)
  where value::text like '%lift%'
);
```

EDIT: Done more bluntly, what if you just cast the whole *topics* array as text and match against that?

```
select *
from your_table
where topics::text like '%lift%';
```

Comment: This looks promising - I'll try it today and update this when I confirm. Thanks!